# QBImagePicker/QBAssetsViewController.m:198:31: No known class method for selector 'labelColor'

Tags: react-native

I am using [react-native-image-crop-picker](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker) in my project (which uses [QBImagePicker](https://github.com/questbeat/QBImagePicker) internally) and now I am getting this error while trying to compile my app. Any ideas?

> Showing Recent Errors Only
>   /Users/me/ReactNativeProjects/myProject/node_modules/react-native-image-crop-picker/ios/QBImagePicker/QBImagePicker/QBAssetsViewController.m:198:31:
>   No known class method for selector 'labelColor'

**Versions**:

react-native-cli: 2.0.1

react-native: 0.61.1

react-native-image-crop-picker@0.26.1

cocoapods: 1.8.3

**Platform**:

iOS 12.2

**Podfile**:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'myProject' do
pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

pod 'RNCharts', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-charts-wrapper'

pod 'QBImagePickerController', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-image-crop-picker/ios/QBImagePicker/QBImagePickerController.podspec'

pod 'RNImageCropPicker', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-image-crop-picker'

pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 6.3.0'

  pre_install do |installer|
    installer.analysis_result.specifications.each do |s|
    s.swift_version = '5.0' unless s.swift_version
  end
end
end
```